# redirect with .htaccess with cakePHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, redirect

cakePHP already set this on /web/website/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now I want to redirect all http to https and www to non-www

I tried:

```
 RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews


  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

INPUT: http://www.example.com.br/website
OUTPUT: https://example.com.br/ with internal server error
SHOULD:  https://example.com.br/website

Comment: Where is your htaccess ? In which folder ? What is your document root folder ?

Comment: @JustinIurman, is /web/website/.htaccess I just replace the cakePHP .htaccess to this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead of using `$1`, using the entire request URI:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on

 // HTTP => HTTPS
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

 // www => http
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

 RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
 RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```